# redirect to login when user have a role request a another view need a role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

You have created roles and added new users
But when I login by the user have a role I redirect to login page in database success add role and add a role to a user

Here I have a problem

```
[Authorize(Roles ="manger")]
public ActionResult show()
{
    return View();
}
```

I'm login with the user have a role manager

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  What is the error (if any) and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Did you misspell the manager role in your roles table too?